# Spring Boot JPA - Many to Many relation creating duplicate entries in one of entity tables

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have to model classes User and Role below -

User.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class User  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String mobile;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Role.class, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH} )
    @JoinTable(
            name="t_user_roles",
            joinColumns=
            @JoinColumn( name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<Role> roles;
```

Role.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_role")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Role  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = User.class, mappedBy = "roles", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private List<User> users;
```

Now when I make separate post requests to create new users A and B both with roles of "user" and "admin", I see two records in the "t_user" table, 4 records in the "t_user_roles" table and 4 records in the "t_role" with duplicate entries for "user" and "admin". Is there any way to avoid creating these duplicate entries?

Using the below controller and service classes to save the User object to the DB

```
@RestController
public class UserController{

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @PostMapping("/user/create")
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        service.createUser(user);
    }
}

public class UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public User createUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you save in your database ?

Comment: Added details above